# Set itemize spacing in Quarto / RMarkdown PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, quarto

In LaTeX, it's easy to control the vertical spacing in an itemized list by using `\setlength\itemsep{1em}`:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemsep{1em}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

How would I control this in Quarto / RMarkdown? If I write an itemized list using just markdown, I can't control the spacing, e.g.:

```
1. one
2. two
3. three
```

Is there a way to set a "global" spacing setting for all itemized or bullet lists? That would work.

Otherwise, is there a way to set the vertical spacing for a markdown list?

Edit:

This is the header I'm using for a Quarto PDF document (I didn't realize the solutions might be sensitive to the document class):

```
---
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrartcl
    papersize: letter
    pdf-engine: xelatex
    geometry:
      - margin=1in
      - heightrounded
    include-in-header:
      - preamble.tex
---
```

Comment: Can you add your header so we can see which format you use?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your are using the quarto pdf format, you could do something like this:

```
---
format: pdf
header-includes:
 - \apptocmd{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}}{}{}
---

1. one
2. two
3. three
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that, this works for only [compact lists](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#bullet-lists)

Comment: adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\setlist{itemsep=10pt}` will make this answer working for loose list also.

Comment: @shafee Unless the OP updates their question to include which documentclass they use, I'd be hesitant to recommend enumitem, that's incompatible with some classes.

Comment: oh! the above suggestion, then simply dictates my lack of knowledge about this incompatibility fact. Thanks!

Comment: @shafee I'm just a bit careful after having answered the question "Why did my beamer bullet points vanish?" with "Don't load enumitem" for about a thousand times :)

Comment: Just noting that this solution worked for the yaml that I posted in my updated question.